# How to refresh data in в popup.html in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have popup.html like:

```
<div id = "info"></div>
```

I have popup.js like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('info', function(items) {
        document.getElementById('info').textContent = items.info;
    });
document.querySelector('#refresh').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    var eventPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    eventPage.refreshAllInfo();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        showInfo();
    }, 3000);

    for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'block ';
    }
});
```

eventpage.js has all logic, that works with data (the refreshAllInfo method) and stores it in the Chrome Local Storage. But, I wish that when the Refresh button is clicked, all div's elements disappear on 3 seconds and the the popup.html demonstrates new data (the showInfo method). But in my code this doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: please post your manifest.json

Comment: Event page is unloaded after 5 seconds of inactivity so chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() will fail. You can use messaging or chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage() with a callback. Anyway, the first and the most important thing you should do is debugging in devtools: right-click the popup, click Inspect, set breakpoints in the code, see what happens when the code runs.

Comment: @wOxxOm, this code actually works in debugger - the elements are being hide and the DevConsole doesn't post any errors. My main question is why elements are not being hide for 3 seconds from popup.html.

Comment: So, I just want to implement the logic that will hide elements from 3 seconds and then show them again. That's it.